# C# Asynchronous Client Socket Example

Tags: c#

I'm looking at an example of the client socket on Microsofts website and I dont understand how this code is async.

```
// Connect to the remote endpoint.  
client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,

new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

connectDone.WaitOne();

//Send test data to the remote device.
Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");

sendDone.WaitOne();
```

The waitone blocks the current thread until the current waithandle receives a signal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example

Also is it possible to write this code using task and wait?

---

When I try to make the SocketAsync with ReceiveAsync I dont seem to be able to await the RecieveAsync .

```
    private async Task<bool> handleReceiveAsync()
    {
        // Get size of frame
        byte[] frameLenData = new byte[4];
        uint frameLen = 0;
        
            bool bOperationFailed = false;
            SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            socketEventArg.SetBuffer(frameLenData, 0, 4);
            socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
            {
            });
          
            return await _socket.ReceiveAsync(socketEventArg);
        
    }
```

Comment: yeah, that's a terrible example of how not to do async! those `WaitOne()` are anathema to async; IMO that should be scrapped - the `WaitOne` removed, and everything under the `WaitOne()` should happen via the callback

Comment: Ya I'm Having alot of issues trying to write the socket asynchronously.
I have read that you should use the  connectasync but all the examples have the waitone and they use the ManualResetEvent aswell

Comment: I've [added feedback for that page](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/26911)

Answer (score 3):

The socket examples on Microsoft's website are known to be extremely bad. The way async is done here is pointless. Async is supposed to not consume a thread (for resource management reasons). This does consume a thread. This is purely worse than synchronous IO.

Modern async IO is done using async/await. It can be this simple:

```
await socket.ReceiveAsync(...);
```

This is using true async IO based on tasks. There are more details to this but I hope this gets you oriented in the right direction.

---

One key point is to "find" the modern Task-based socket APIs. `Socket` has legacy APIs for compatibility reasons. In the code snipped posted in the question, this is an EAP-style API which, while not entirely obsolete, is something that almost never should be used.

So you have to pick the correct overloads. Look at intellisense or documentation to see what is there. You want something that returns a task. Here is a self-contained example:

```
        using var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        await socket.ConnectAsync("example.org", 80);

        await socket.SendAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"), SocketFlags.None);

        await using var result = new MemoryStream();
        await using var networkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        await networkStream.CopyToAsync(result);

        var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

Using sockets correctly is still a bit more involved than this. Unfortunately, it's more than this margin will contain. So I encourage you to research sockets a bit more. Hope this helps you get started.

Try to use a modern style with modern APIs and modern patterns. They are much better.

Comment: I dont seem to be able to await the ReceiveAsync command. See code above

Comment: @Sean I added some more. Sockets can be hard to get started with because most content on the web is outdated or just bad. It really is not that hard but there's so much noise.